# Minimum special characters, Uppercase and numbers

Tags: regex

Friends,
it is possible to validate the special characters minimum, Uppercase the minimum and minimum of number in a single regex?

Example of string:

```
var str = "abc@A123"
```

what I wan:

I want a single regex to validate at least 2 special characters, 2 numbers and 2 capital letters

Comment: Maximum of minimums here.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want the regex to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want a single regex to validate at least 2 special characters, 2 numbers and 2 capital letters. thank you :)

Comment: FWIW, each of these checks is pretty trivial in itself, and your code will be a lot saner if you tackle each step individually, even if that takes a bit more code.

Comment: @deceze thank you, I came to this conclusion also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding the question I'm pretty sure you are looking for the positive or negative lookaround which is in most regex dialects.

For example:

```
(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])       #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])      #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {6,20}  #        length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20
)           # End of group
```

source: https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

Comment: thank you, your response was essential for me to get the solution of my problem

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to find the `number` of `special characters` used.

```
var str = "abc@A123"; 
var foundSpecialChar = str.match(/[@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g);
alert(foundSpecialChar.length);//count
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zpz16504/